# Spark SQL - How can I create a temporary table with hardcoded values?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a hardcoded table so that I can use it as a left join elsewhere.

```
Color
Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
```

I tried alot of combinations like

```
with TempTable as (
select * from ("red","blue","green","yellow") as color 
)
```

but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-inline-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Temporary Approach

You may use **inline tables**

```sql
SELECT * from VALUES ("Red"),("Blue"), ("Green"), ("Yellow") as Colors (color)
```

Example As a **Common Table Expressions (CTEs)**:

```sql
WITH colors as (
   SELECT * from VALUES ("Red"),("Blue"), ("Green"), ("Yellow") as Colors (color)
)
SELECT 
  tbl1.*,
  colors.color
FROM
  tbl1
LEFT JOIN
  colors ON tbl1.color = colors.color
```

Example as a **subquery**:

```sql
SELECT 
  tbl1.*,
  colors.color
FROM
  tbl1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * from VALUES ("Red"),("Blue"), ("Green"), ("Yellow") as Colors (color)) colors
  ON tbl1.color = colors.color
```

#### Persisting this table

```
create table colors AS
SELECT * from VALUES ("Red"),("Blue"), ("Green"), ("Yellow") as Colors (color)
```

You could then query this as regular table

#### Reference

[Inline Tables](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-inline-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a temp view:

```
create or replace temp view TempTable as (
    select * from values ('Red'), ('Blue'), ('Green'), ('Yellow')
)
```